# Drupal view shows multiple results to a single row

Tags: views

I am using a view with table format.

I need to show results in a given format. I am unable to find..

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to achieve in views..

Thanks

Comment: Plain CSS. Just style each views row to be approximately 50% of the parent container, set the border, add right margin to `odd` ones and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Set the format of the view to "grid" and columns to 2.
Option 2: Set the format of the view to "HTML list" and then with css set the width of the li and float it left.